# Ajax function doesn't execute when any of the input fields are not supplied in django

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django

I have below ajax function, which is working fine when I input values for all the fields, but it doesn't work when I do not supply value to any of the three fields (pname,psection, and rinput-json)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function saveprof() {
            $('.spinner').show();
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "saveprof",
                enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
                async: true,
                data: {
                    'pname_Aj': $('#pname').val(),
                    'psection_Aj': $('#psection').val(),
                    'rinput_Aj' : JSON.stringify(fun()),
                    'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
                },
                success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                    $('#message').html(data);
                    window.location.href = 'myprofile';
                    window.location('myprofile');  
                    $('.spinner').fadeOut();
                }
            });
        }
</script>
```

How can I make it work even if the values for any of the fields are not supplied ?

For your information, this call is made to the Django view which does save the fields in the database.

Comment: what does it do when `it doesn't work`?

Comment: I have kept a div named spinner to appear in saveprof() function.. it was just an image which gets displayed.. and I can see ajax function is not getting executed for sure when I miss any of those three fields..

Comment: Use console and check for any errors. You can open console using F12. My best guess for the problem is wrong url. Try using 
url:'/saveprof' or give absolute path in url.

Comment: Hi Shah, URL part is correct.. because ajax function executes when I input values in all the fields... it doesn't work only when any of the field values is missing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like those values are optional?

If so, perhaps you can check to see if those values exist, and if not, just submit an empty string:

```
data: {
                'pname_Aj': ( $('#pname').val() || ""),
                'psection_Aj': ( $('#psection').val() || ""),
                'rinput_Aj' : (JSON.stringify(fun()) || ""),
                'csrfmiddlewaretoken':$("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
            },
```

So if the user has entered values in those sections (and `fun()` returns something that can be stringified, those variables get submitted. Otherwise, an empty string gets submitted.

Comment: Hi, I updated the function with this, but I still see it is not working..  Ajax function is working only when I submit values for all the fields :(.. May be I can try to see if below works for each field ?           -                                                                                                                                                                             var input = document.getElementById('pname');

if(input.value.length == 0)
    input.value = " ";

Answer (score 0):

If the parameters need to be absent when no value

```
function saveprof() {
    $('.spinner').show();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "saveprof",
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        async: true,
        data : function() {
            var data = {};
            var addToData = function(name, val) {
                if(val) {
                    data[name] = val;
                }
            }
            addToData('pname_Aj', $('#pname').val());
            addToData('psection_Aj', $('#psection').val());
            addToData('rinput_Aj', JSON.stringify(fun()));
            addToData('csrfmiddlewaretoken', $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val());
            return data;
        }(),
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#message').html(data);
            window.location.href = 'myprofile';
            window.location('myprofile');  
            $('.spinner').fadeOut();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hi Jaromanda, thanks for this.. but in my case, I would need the parameter.